# agregar en bd una fecha 2 dias despues de hoy sin contar sabado y domingo en mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, date

tengo un insert en base datos mysql de fechas,

estoy utilizando el comando date_sub para sumar 4 dias a la fecha actual,

```
    $fecha_actual = now();
    INSERT INTO TABLA_FECHAS (preparar, llamar) VALUES 
(' . $fecha_actual .',date_sub(' . $fecha_actual .',INTERVAL 2 DAY)),
```

necesito que si la $fecha_actual es el viernes al hacer el insert into no cuente el dia sabado ni domingo, es decir al insertar el campo llamar, debe sumar 2 dias al viernes pero sin contar sabado y domingo. deberia de ser el dia martes.

que comando date_sub puedo agregar para que no cuente el sabado ni domingo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que lo que tenes que usar en este punto es la funcion [`DAYOFWEEK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) en ocnjunto con un if, ademas, para sumar dias hay que usar la funcion date_add en lugar de date_sub :

```
INSERT INTO TABLA_FECHAS (preparar, llamar)
VALUES (
    '$fecha_actual',
    IF( DAYOFWEEK('$fecha_actual')=6,
        DATE_ADD('$fecha_actual',INTERVAL 4 DAY),
        DATE_ADD('$fecha_actual',INTERVAL 2 DAY)
    )
);
```